# Copy sheets to newly created files

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that filters for unique values in a table and copies them into workbooks with the same name as the unique value.

I would like to add two sheets to these workbooks, no filter or anything.
These sheets are in the source file called let's say "Bonus" and "Time".

How do I incorporate this into below code?

```vb
Sub filter()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim last As Long
Dim sht As String
Dim newBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim Workbk As Excel.Workbook

sht = "kalkulátor"

Set Workbk = ThisWorkbook

last = Workbk.Sheets(sht).Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row

With Workbk.Sheets(sht)
    Set rng = .Range("A1:y" & last)
End With

Workbk.Sheets(sht).Range("B1:B" & last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("AA1"), Unique:=True

For Each x In Workbk.Sheets(sht).Range([AA2], Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp))

    With rng
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=x.Value
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

        Set newBook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

        newBook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
        newBook.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End With

    newBook.SaveAs x.Value & ".xlsx"

    newBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Next x

' Turn off filter
Workbk.Sheets(sht).AutoFilterMode = False

With Application
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

I tried this:

```
Sheets("Time").Copy After:=Workbooks.newBook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sheets("Time")` is equalient to `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Time")`. The active workbook is `newBook` after creating new workbook. There isn't `Time` sheet in `newBook`. That's the reason why it doesn't work.

`Sheets("Time").Copy After:=Workbooks.newBook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)`

---

- Copy sheets before save new created workbook, qualify sheet object with `Workbk`
- Two sheets can be copied all at once
- Revised `For Each` to fully qualify all range reference

```vb
    Dim aSht, oSht As Worksheet '**
    aSht = Array("Bonus", "Time") '**
    Set oSht = Workbk.Sheets(sht) '**
    For Each x In oSht.Range(oSht.[AA2], oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp)) '**
        With rng
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=x.Value
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            Set newBook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
            newBook.Sheets.Add(After:=newBook.Sheets(newBook.Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
            ' newBook.Activate
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End With
        Workbk.Sheets(aSht).Copy After:=newBook.Sheets(newBook.Sheets.Count) '**
        newBook.SaveAs x.Value & ".xlsx"
        newBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next x
```